# Passing data from v-for list card to corresponding modal

Tags: list, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm building this plants database (see the link below). When you hover the plant card, you see basic stats, and when you click on "Mais informações", corresponding modal opens, showing more information.

http://www.verdeasy.com.br/

The question is: How can I pass the data from v-for list cards to showing them in the modals, obviously outside the v-for cards div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the selected plan to a variable and display that in the modal like this:

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    plants: ['Cebolinha', 'Coentro', 'Louro'],
    plant: null
  })
}).$mount('#app');
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in plants">{{p}} <button href="#" @click="plant = p">details</button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="modal" v-if="plant">
    {{plant}}
    <button @click="plant = null">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```